# malloc error checking methods

Tags: c, malloc

I have seen a few different ways of doing malloc error checking. Is one way better than the other? Are some exit codes better than others? Is using fprintf with stderr better than using a printf statement? Is using a return instead of an exit better?

```
    ptr=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));  //memory allocated using malloc
    if(ptr==NULL)                     
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }

    ptr=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));  //memory allocated using malloc
    if(ptr==NULL)                     
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(1);
    }

    res = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);
    if (!res) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed: insufficient memory!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ptr=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));  //memory allocated using malloc
    if(ptr==NULL)                     
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(-1);
    }

   ptr=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));  //memory allocated using malloc
    if(ptr==NULL)                     
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * some_int);
if (ptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory.\n");
    return -1;
}

char* allocCharBuffer(size_t numberOfChars) 
{
    char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * numberOfChars);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Errors should be written to stderr.  When exiting with an error, exit status should be non-zero.  If a malloc failure should result in a fatal error and immediate exit, consider wrapping it in a function that reports the error and exits, so you don't have to check the return value in your code.

Comment: The book is out of print now, but "C Unleashed" by Richard Heathfield et al has an interesting chapter about strategies you can use to try to *recover* from `malloc` failures. A user of a word processor doesn't want the application to crash just because the operation that they are attempting runs into memory resource limits. At the very least, if there is some relevant notion of state, perhaps state can be saved somehow before exiting. Don't think that a `malloc` failure has to automatically terminate your program.

Comment: [Do not cast the return value of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: This has nothing to do with malloc specifically, does it? Plenty of things can fail.

Comment: @rockstar797 don't forget to add an answer as accepted if your problem is soved ;-)

Comment: @rockstar797 Haha that's a common problem :p you are supposed to accept the one which solved your problem but here, i understand it can be a bit confusing

Comment: @Magix not sure which one to accept. They are all good answers. Every answer seems to clarify it a bit more. Wish I could combine them all into one answer.

Answer (score 13):

How about this wrapper:

```
void *safe_malloc(size_t n)
{
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: failed to allocate %zu bytes.\n", n);
        abort();
    }
    return p;
}
```

Then just use `safe_malloc` everywhere, and don't worry about the error checking.

Many programs are not written to gracefully handle memory allocation failures, and this solution is just fine for those applications. If your application *is* able to continue after memory allocation failures, then you probably wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain why you dislike this solution?

Comment: I downvoted because, depending of the context, the application may need to `free` some variables before leaving, even in applications which don't need to continue after allocation failures. This is not possible with this wrapper, and may cause memory leaks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but aborting the program after an allocation failure is hardly "safe" when you have other memory that needs freed... That aside, you also might want to change `%zd` to `%zu` in your `printf()` format string to match `size_t` rather than the signed equivalent (`ssize_t` on a POSIX system).

Comment: @Magix Memory leaks are the least of your worries when your application is out of memory. All of the process's memory is returned to the kernel when it exits anyway.

Comment: @Chrono thanks, changed to %zu. But again, freeing memory before you abort is pointless.

Comment: Also if you are going to downvote this answer for that reason you need to downvote all other answers as well.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart would this function be called like this? `safe_malloc(sizeof(n))` Are we assuming this is a char? Wouldn't you need to something a bit different if its int because its bigger?

Comment: @rockstar797 it obviously depends on what you're trying to allocate. As I said, this function is a drop-in replacement for malloc that requires no error checking.

Comment: Please note that fprintf may also perform mallocs. So then that printf may also fail.

Answer (score 12):

When you detect an error with `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()` (i.e they return a NULL pointer), the POSIX98 standard dictates that `errno` must be set (see `man malloc`). You can then use the standard function `perror()` to print the error without the need to do your own formatting. Note that it will automatically print to `stderr`, no need to bother with that.

Furthermore, If your application considers the error as fatal, then the process must be ended. If your code is located in the `main()` function, then using `return EXIT_FAILURE;` is fine, and use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` if not. It is not recommended to exit with your own return code in that case.
If the error is not considered as fatal, then it's up to you how to handle it.

Please also note that, when `realloc()` fails and returns `NULL`, the old pointer is still valid and must therefore be `free`d before leaving.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to dictate that allocation failures should always be considered fatal. That is really up to the application. The application may have a way to recover such as freeing up some memory and retrying the allocation or retrying with a smaller allocation or even just waiting for a while and trying again later in cases where memory usage across the application may be transient.

Comment: @M.M I didn't mean to check for errors using errno, but only if errors are detected then `perror()` will do its job. I will edit to make this clearer

Comment: Updated : The Posix98 standard actually enforces `errno` to be set, as described in my answer. See `man malloc` and the posix standard. Non-compliant implementations are undefined behaviour

Answer (score 2):

It is not about how you check the error, It is what you do with the error. In all the cases you can see that the common piece of code used is

`if (ptr == NULL) {....}`

When you encounter the return value is `NULL`, what you do after that is your personal choice. Some devs even like to `assert()` the program.

in the meantime gcc sets the errno for you. So you can use that to get more details and use it as well.

In summary you can do whatever suits you most for your program.

Answer (score 1):

Rule #1. Always check `malloc`'s return value (and `realloc`'s) for errors.

Rule #2. Unless you can recover gracefully, always print an error message to `stderr`, giving relevant information.

Rule #3. Always exit with a nonzero status of there is an error.  (The exact nonzero value doesn't matter so much.)

A "wrapper" function is an excellent way of addressing all three rules at the same time, *if* your program can tolerate exiting precipitously (that is, without saving any in-memory data which might be vital).

There are some exceptions to Rule #2, but they still involve reporting the error somehow (just not necessarily with an immediate `fprintf` to `stderr`), so the basic rule stands.

Answer (score 0):

```
perror("more details");
```

will (attempt to) print the error (as per the errno) to `stderr`.
You can use that.

```
static void die(const char* msg){ perror(msg); exit(1); }
```

You could also save the errno and translate it to a BSD style sysexits.h code or just somehow linearly serialize it to the parent process (by `exit`ing with the errno or a linear translation thereof).